# How can we switch between two modules in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two modules in my application. The requirement is that I need to navigate from one module to another. Is it possible?

The two modules are sol user and sol cutomer are 2 different module. This way it is not working? Am i doing something wrong? Any other alternative please

The code which i am using is given below but it is not displaying anything

```
'use strict';
(function () {

  angular.module('sol.user')
  .config(StateConfig);
  StateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

  alert("user-state");
  function StateConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.when('/customer/search', '/user');
       $stateProvider
          .state('home.user',{
            url:'/user',
            controller:'sol.user.UserController',
            controllerAs: 'userCtrl'
        })
        .state('home.search', {
                url: '/customer/search',
                templateUrl: 'views/customer/search/search.html',
                controller: 'sol.customer.search.SearchCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'searchCtrl'
            })




  }
})();
```

Comment: 'use strict';
(function () {var user = angular.module('sol.user', []);
   user.controller('sol.user.UserController', UserController);
     $scope.profiles ="";
    $scope.userId ="";    
   function UserController($scope, $http){
    alert("Hello");
    $http({method: 'GET',
      url: 'rest/user/details'})
      .success(function(data) {
          $scope.profiles = data;
                })
      .error(function(data) {
         $scope.profiles = data;
          alert( "failure");
          alert( data);
      });
    $state.go('home.search');
   }
})();

Comment: you have not mentioned template url for user state in StateConfig